# In excel VBA how do you increase a number in one column by one based on the value changing in another column

Tags: excel, vba

I have two columns in excel. One is a company name. The other column is an invoice number that should only increment upon change in company name. The beginning invoice number should be input 
Input Beginning Invoice number => 1001. What is the VBA code to increment the invoice number each time a new company occurs?

```
Company A      1001
Company A      1001
Company A      1001
Company B      1002
Company B      1002
Company C      1003
```

Comment: This can be done with a simple formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could be solved be either formula or VBA code.

Logic is to see if your current cell with the company name is the same as the previous cell. If they are the same then copy previous value. Otherwise increase the invoice number with 1.

**Formula**, starts in cell `C2`:

```
=IF(A1=A2,C1,C1+1)
```

[image]

**VBA code**:

You might need to change the column number so it fits your dataset.

```
Sub IncreaseNumber()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lrow As Long
Dim i As Long

Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1") 'Name the worksheet

lrow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'find the lastrow in column A

For i = 2 To lrow 'Loop from second row to the last row
   If ws.Cells(i - 1, "A").Value = ws.Cells(i, "A").Value Then 'If cell "i -1" and cell "i" is equal then
        ws.Cells(i, "B").Value = ws.Cells(i - 1, "B").Value 'take the same value as row above
    Else
        ws.Cells(i, "B").Value = ws.Cells(i - 1, "B").Value + 1 'if not the same, then add 1 to the invoice number
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: One assumption for another doing this is the list of company's is sorted. I added a line before implementing the logic above to sort the sheet by company name.

Comment: You are totally right @cknowlan. I just assumed that the column A was sorted.